# Java scsi access

Tags: java, c, linux, porting, scsi

I'd like to port a Linux C program to Java. This program controls a camera which is connected to the PC with a USB cable. The C code uses Linux SCSI Generic (sg).

Sample code from the C program:

```
#include <linux/../scsi/sg.h>

...

static int scsi_write(int sg_fd, uint8_t *cmd, uint32_t cmdLen,
               uint8_t *buf, uint32_t bufLen) {

    sg_io_hdr_t io;
    int r;

    memset(&io, 0, sizeof(io));

    io.interface_id = 'S';
    io.cmd_len = cmdLen;

    ...        
    r = ioctl(sg_fd, SG_IO, &io);
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to port this program to Java? I was searching for a cross-platform SCSI library written for Java, but found none. I was also searching for a JNI over SCSI/sg, also no luck.

Comment: Are you looking to implement it on Linux, or specifically cross-platform?

Comment: Why would you want to port that to Java? I don't see any gain in porting that kind of hardware-dependent code to Java. Maybe you'd want to wrap the HW-access in a C library and invoke that from Java via JNI. That way you could (for example) write the GUI in Java and still use your working and tested C code for the HW access.

Comment: Cross-platform would be better of course.

Comment: @Joachim: He wants to access a USB device using Java. Why is that more "hardware-depentent" than anything else commonly done with Java, like accessing the keyboard, mouse, network, display, printers etc?

Comment: why porting: If it's not possible I won't port it. I just wanted to know if it's possible. Maybe someone else already tried to port a similar code and can give me a few hints.

Comment: @jarnbjo: because keyboards, mice, network cards, displays and printers have all got abstractions in the Java platform (and in most OS), that allow some kind of hardware-independent interaction with those. Using SCSI-level APIs is by definition hardware-dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Java supports a lot of the POSIX API, the `ioctl` system call is not part of what it does. What you'll need to do is to use JNI to allow Java to call a function such as the `scsi_write` you wrote in the question. The extra cost of using more shims is minimal given that you're talking about interfacing to external hardware anyway. The `cmd` and `buf` arguments map naturally to Java byte arrays (and since Java's arrays know their length, you won't model the `cmdLen` and `bufLen` arguments at the Java level at all).

Comment: And no, stuff using `ioctl` is only very rarely portable. It's a syscall for passing information directly to the driver or device, and that's never going to be a highly portable thing.

Answer (score 2):

You may have more luck with a Java based USB library, like an implementation of JSR080 (javax.usb). You can find the reference implementation [here](http://javax-usb.sourceforge.net/), but only the Linux implementation is kind of production ready.

Answer (score 0):

Please try IOCTL, you may want to have a look at sg3_utils source code to learn how to send SCSI PDU by ioctl, it's C code, but PDU and ioctl are the same. Then you know you can control the camera.